# Android and strange error with maps from google

Tags: android, google-maps

I create application where I use google maps. I get error:

```
06-20 15:23:51.262: W/System.err(28660): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
06-20 15:23:51.272: W/System.err(28660):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
06-20 15:23:51.272: W/System.err(28660):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
06-20 15:23:51.272: W/System.err(28660):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
06-20 15:23:51.272: W/System.err(28660):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
06-20 15:23:51.272: W/System.err(28660):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
06-20 15:23:51.272: W/System.err(28660):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Could you tell me what is a reason this error?

Comment: can you please paste your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your map api key is the issue..., generate correct map key for your apk with the same keystore you are using to create apk. To check in the emulator create api key for your SDK.

Refer these links: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

[Does a new Debug Keystore mean a new Map API Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020565/does-a-new-debug-keystore-mean-a-new-map-api-key)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the issue was the **map api key** , which wasn't the same in the `google-services.json` and in the `AndroidManifest` :

In google-services.json:

```
"api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "*********************"
        }
      ]
```

In AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="*********************" />
```