# Android Studio-Google maps doesn't show map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to create a google maps activity using the google maps api in android studio. I generated the API key and pasted it in the google_maps_api.xml`. My manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.l5434.project">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <permission android:name="com.example.l5434.project" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name="pubsub.subscriber.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
        <activity android:name="pubsub.subscriber.SubscriberActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I also added the dependency `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'` in my `build.gradle` but it didn't solve the problem.
This is how the emulator looks when the maps activity starts.

[image]

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Do you have this in your build.gradle as well: "implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'" . What kind of misbehavior are you seeing?

Comment: follow this https://abhiandroid.com/programming/googlemaps

Comment: are you seeing the google logo in the map?

Comment: I added a printscreen of the emulator when the maps activity starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is usually related to the map API key used to sign manifest. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296467/google-map-signed-api-key-errors-in-android) post and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120522/android-and-strange-error-with-maps-from-google) which describe the same error you are experiencing. In both cases it is because the API key they used was created with the wrong keystore. You need to make sure you use your debug `keystore` when you create an API key in the Google API console